# How can I pass images in a server's response using JSON? Base64?

Tags: python, android, image, listview, base64

In my android app, I show some users in a ListView. I want to display (user's pic, first_name, last_name). Right now, it works only with first_name and last_name. I want to add the picture. The data JSON I receive from my server (python) is like this:

```
[{"profil":"first_name": "Jim", "last_name": "Carrey"}}, "_id": {"$oid": "4d595cda1d41c81536000000"}}, {"profil":{"first_name": "Mathieu", "last_name": "Polnari"}}, "_id": {"$oid": "4d5916581d41c80e88000000"}}, {"profil": {"first_name": "Vincent", "last_name": "Fatou"}}, "_id": {"$oid": "4d58fc7e1d41c8090e000000"}}...]
```

It should be better if I add one parameter in that JSON for the picture.

Do you think it is a good idea to return the picture as a string in the JSON et use Base64 to decode it?

Comment: Would you be able to explain how to convert an image using Base64 to JSON?  This would help me.  Seems like you know how to do it and were just asking whether there were any costs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Technically it's perfectly ok to encode binary data as base64 string and include it in JSON.

But, as @servermanfail noted, you might be better off with embedding links to images into JSON and downloading them in the second step.

The added benefit would be size/speed of transfer, as base64 stream is 4/3 the size of the original binary stream (33% overhead).

Also, in this case, you could cache images.

Comment: It will be more difficult for me because I want to set the text and picture on the PostExecute() of my AsynTask which get the JSON. If I download the picture in another thread it will occurs a problem.

Comment: The only issue I could see could be performance and memory consumption. You should do some tests with your typical image sizes.

Comment: If the pictures are very small, the overhead of a separate request for each might be more than what you waste by using base64.

Comment: Yep. I will try with base64, it's easier to implement both in the client and server side, I need only to decode the response. If it's too long to decode, I will take a look at downloading images with url. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Thomas K: the images are just little preview of profil pic. The number of users can exceed 15 users... I have to decide if I download 15 little images in 15 different requests, or just decode them with base64. What do you think?

Comment: @user420574: For the thumbnails at the size they appear on SO questions/answers, I wouldn't be surprised if base64 was more efficient. But if it's important, do some tests to find out for your site.

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest adding a JSON parameter which contains a URL to the resource.

For added security, you could create encrypted URLs by adding a md5 with salt checksum to the resource, like http://server.com/images/1234567890123456789012345678901234567890/image.jpg - this is the method facebook.com uses.

Comment: MD5 is not an [encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) and thus cannot be decrypted.

Comment: There is no need to decrypt file name - you can keep this MD5-references next to image name in the database. The whole point of MD5-ing the image name it to prevent guessing it.